# How can I print json in my ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am returning json from server but it's not available in my success callback in ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'myData.php',
    type:'post',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data.name); // This should print my name
    }
});
```

In php I am using this

```
$data=array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'john');
echo json_encode($data);
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: inspect element in chrome and check the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

1. Tell jQuery that you are expecting JSON data back. See *dataType* on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

   or
2. Return a header so that jQuery can detect the response as being JSON:

   ```
    header('Content-type: application/json');
   ```